# Make the Edit option work in a CRUD in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I can't make the edit option work, the add option works and the UI is working fine but when i select the option edit it sends me where im going to edit but it doesn't let me write or delete anything.

I can't make the Edit option work, im using a hook called useForm.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const reset = () => {
    setValues(initialState);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (target) => {
    console.log(target.value);
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    });
  };

  return {
    values,
    handleInputChange,
    reset,
  };
};
```

Then i called it in the file where it was suposed to edit but it doesn't let me to write anything.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "./context/GlobalState";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "./context/useForm";

const EditUser = () => {
  const { values, handleInputChange } = useForm({
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    description: "",
    location: "",
    services: "",
    price: "",
    schedule: "",
  });

  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
    name: values.name,
    lastName: values.lastName,
    email: values.email,
    description: values.description,
    location: values.location,
    services: values.services,
    price: values.price,
    schedule: values.schedule,
  });

  const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const history = useNavigate();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const currentUserId = id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = currentUserId;
    const selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  }, [currentUserId, users]);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    editUser(selectedUser);
    history("/customers");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        className="w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center"
      >
        <div className="box-border shadow-md bg-white border-current border-1 h-4/5 w-4/12 p-4 rounded-xl flex justify-center place-items-center flex-col text-black">
          <p className="text-lg font-semibold">
            Actualiza los datos del usuario
          </p>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={selectedUser.name}
              // onChange={onChangeName}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Nombre"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              value={selectedUser.lastName}
              // onChange={onChangeLastName}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Apellidos"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value={selectedUser.email}
              // onChange={onChangeEmail}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Correo electronico"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="description"
              value={selectedUser.description}
              // onChange={onChangeDescription}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Descripcion"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="location"
              value={selectedUser.location}
              // onChange={onChangeLocation}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Ubicacion"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="services"
              value={selectedUser.services}
              // onChange={onChangeServices}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Servicios"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="price"
              value={selectedUser.price}
              // onChange={onChangePrice}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Precio"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="schedule"
              value={selectedUser.schedule}
              // onChange={onChangeEmail}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleInputChange(target)}
              className="textfield-outline"
              placeholder="Horarios"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button
            type="addUser"
            className="normal-button"
            onClick={() => onSubmit()}
          >
            Actualizar
          </button>
          <Link to="/customers">
            <button type="cancel" className="normal-button">
              Cancelar
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditUser;
```

Comment: Remove that state entirely and it will work: `const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
    name: values.name,
    lastName: values.lastName,
    email: values.email,
    description: values.description,
    location: values.location,
    services: values.services,
    price: values.price,
    schedule: values.schedule,
  });
`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work because i need to define the selectedUser. I use the selectedUser in the useEffect and in the onSubmit.

Comment: You have this data in `values`

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand how to implement `values` instead of `selectedUser`

Comment: You already have `values`, just remove the state, `useForm` is enough